# Doxygen - Objective-C - Document Private Class functions Private

Tags: objective-c, class, private, doxygen

In doxygen, I can create objective-c categories inside my implementation file to hide interfaces that shouldn't be accessed publicly. However, doxygen still documents the category as the members being "public". Even by adding the \protected or \private, this is still the case.

Is there another method that I'm overlooking that would put this in a "Private Methods" section of that category...or better yet in the same document that the public class is in only listed as private?

Here's part of my config:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Project related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME           = "My Project"
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = /Users/theuser/Development/myApplication/Documentation
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = 
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = 
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    = 
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 8
ALIASES                = 
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = 
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = YES
SYMBOL_CACHE_SIZE      = 0

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = YES
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = YES
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = YES
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = YES
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       = 
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_DIRECTORIES       = NO
SHOW_FILES             = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    = 
LAYOUT_FILE            =
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `\internal` in code, coupled with `INTERNAL_DOCS = NO` in Doxyfile?

Another way to put some part of the code out of doxygen scope is to use `\cond` and `\endcond` commands.

Comment: Yup, when I try that, the function still seems to appear, but the detailed description disappears.

Comment: I'll have to try using the \cond and \endcond. That sounds promising since it seems like something that doxygen is simply overlooking.